# Use map function to change field value using xslt 3.0

Tags: xslt, hashmap

I need to map field value from hash table only in Debtor field and other values remains same.
I want the all other fields to be as it is and only change the map the debtor fields.

P_BPMapping - {"BANK1":"1","BANK2":"2","BANK3":"3","BANK4":"4"}

My input xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<JECreateRequest>
    <MessageHeader>
    </MessageHeader>
        <JournalEntryCreateRequest>
            <MessageHeader>
                <JournalEntry>
                    <DebtorItem>
                        <Debtor>BANK1</Debtor>
                    </DebtorItem>
                </JournalEntry>
            </MessageHeader>
        </JournalEntryCreateRequest>
                <JournalEntryCreateRequest>
            <MessageHeader>
                <JournalEntry>
                    <DebtorItem>
                        <Debtor>BANK2</Debtor>
                    </DebtorItem>
                    <DebtorItem>
                        <Debtor>BANK1</Debtor>
                    </DebtorItem>
                </JournalEntry>
            </MessageHeader>
        </JournalEntryCreateRequest>
                <JournalEntryCreateRequest>
            <MessageHeader>
                <JournalEntry>
                    <DebtorItem>
                        <Debtor>BANK4</Debtor>
                    </DebtorItem>
                    <DebtorItem>
                        <Debtor>BANK3</Debtor>
                    </DebtorItem>
                    <DebtorItem>
                        <Debtor>BANK1</Debtor>
                    </DebtorItem>
                </JournalEntry>
            </MessageHeader>
        </JournalEntryCreateRequest>
</JournalEntryBulkCreateRequest>
```

Hash Table
BANK1 - 1
BANK2 - 2
BANK3 - 3
BANK4 - 4

My XSLT code - I have tried with this XSLT code and getting error.

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="3.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<!-- Start of enhancement - ValueMapping for Payloution Customer -->
    <xsl:param name="P_BPMapping" />
    <xsl:param name="MapDebitor" as="map(*)" select="parse-json($P_BPMapping)" />
    <!-- End of enhancement -->

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!--
<xsl:for-each select ="MessageHeader/JournalEntryCreateRequest/JournalEntry/DebtorItem">
-->
<xsl:template match="MessageHeader">
    <xsl:for-each select ="JournalEntryCreateRequest/JournalEntry/DebtorItem">
            <xsl:template match="Debtor">
                <xsl:copy>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="map:get($MapDebitor,Debtor)">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="map:get($MapDebitor,Debtor)" />
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <error>
                                        <xsl:text>Error in BusinessPartner mapping. Please maintain the mapping for the following debtor: </xsl:text>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="Debtor"/>
                                    </error>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>               
                
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:template>
    </xsl:for-each>        
</xsl:template>
<!--
</xsl:for-each>
-->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected output

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <JECreateRequest>
        <MessageHeader>
        </MessageHeader>
            <JournalEntryCreateRequest>
                <MessageHeader>
                    <JournalEntry>
                        <DebtorItem>
                            <Debtor>1</Debtor>
                        </DebtorItem>
                    </JournalEntry>
                </MessageHeader>
            </JournalEntryCreateRequest>
                    <JournalEntryCreateRequest>
                <MessageHeader>
                    <JournalEntry>
                        <DebtorItem>
                            <Debtor>2</Debtor>
                        </DebtorItem>
                        <DebtorItem>
                            <Debtor>1</Debtor>
                        </DebtorItem>
                    </JournalEntry>
                </MessageHeader>
            </JournalEntryCreateRequest>
                    <JournalEntryCreateRequest>
                <MessageHeader>
                    <JournalEntry>
                        <DebtorItem>
                            <Debtor>4</Debtor>
                        </DebtorItem>
                        <DebtorItem>
                            <Debtor>3</Debtor>
                        </DebtorItem>
                        <DebtorItem>
                            <Debtor>1</Debtor>
                        </DebtorItem>
                    </JournalEntry>
                </MessageHeader>
            </JournalEntryCreateRequest>
    </JournalEntryBulkCreateRequest>
```

Comment: Please don't tell us you're getting an error without telling us what the error is. The error message is where problem solving starts.

Comment: How did you supply the value of the parameter(s) to the stylesheet?

Answer (score 1):

I would use e.g.

```
  <xsl:param name="map-data" as="xs:string" expand-text="no">{"BANK1":"1","BANK2":"2","BANK3":"3","BANK4":"4"}</xsl:param>

  <xsl:param name="map" select="parse-json($map-data)"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="Debtor[map:contains($map, .)]">
    <xsl:copy>{$map(.)}</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
```

(with `xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"` and `expand-text="yes"` being declared in the XSLT).

Your code also seems to try to find non-matching `Debtor`s and output some error so perhaps an additional template

```
  <xsl:template match="Debtor[not(map:contains($map, .))]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <error>Error in BusinessPartner mapping. Please maintain the mapping for the following debtor: {.}</error>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

is needed, though the input/output samples don't show that case.

[Online sample demo](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Amap%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2005%2Fxpath-functions%2Fmap%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0D%0A%20%20expand-text%3D%22yes%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aparam%20name%3D%22map-data%22%20as%3D%22xs%3Astring%22%20expand-text%3D%22no%22%3E%7B%22BANK1%22%3A%221%22%2C%22BANK2%22%3A%222%22%2C%22BANK3%22%3A%223%22%2C%22BANK4%22%3A%224%22%7D%3C%2Fxsl%3Aparam%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aparam%20name%3D%22map%22%20select%3D%22parse-json%28%24map-data%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22Debtor%5Bmap%3Acontains%28%24map%2C%20.%29%5D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acopy%3E%7B%24map%28.%29%7D%3C%2Fxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amode%20on-no-match%3D%22shallow-copy%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%20name%3D%22xsl%3Ainitial-template%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Anext-match%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acomment%3ERun%20with%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27xsl%3Aproduct-name%27%29%7D%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27xsl%3Aproduct-version%27%29%7D%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27Q%7Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fsaxon.sf.net%2F%7Dplatform%27%29%7D%3C%2Fxsl%3Acomment%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0D%0A&input=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3CJECreateRequest%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CMessageHeader%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FMessageHeader%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CJournalEntryCreateRequest%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CMessageHeader%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CJournalEntry%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CDebtorItem%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CDebtor%3EBANK1%3C%2FDebtor%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FDebtorItem%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FJournalEntry%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FMessageHeader%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FJournalEntryCreateRequest%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CJournalEntryCreateRequest%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CMessageHeader%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CJournalEntry%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CDebtorItem%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CDebtor%3EBANK2%3C%2FDebtor%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FDebtorItem%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CDebtorItem%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CDebtor%3EBANK1%3C%2FDebtor%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FDebtorItem%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FJournalEntry%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FMessageHeader%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FJournalEntryCreateRequest%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CJournalEntryCreateRequest%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CMessageHeader%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CJournalEntry%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CDebtorItem%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CDebtor%3EBANK4%3C%2FDebtor%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FDebtorItem%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CDebtorItem%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CDebtor%3EBANK3%3C%2FDebtor%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FDebtorItem%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CDebtorItem%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CDebtor%3EBANK1%3C%2FDebtor%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FDebtorItem%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FJournalEntry%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FMessageHeader%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FJournalEntryCreateRequest%3E%0D%0A%3C%2FJECreateRequest%3E&input-type=XML).